# Google spreadsheet counts google docs in the google drive folder by tags in the description

Tags: google-sheets, automation, google-drive-api

I have documents on google drive, in the description of which tags are indicated (the text after the # sign separated by a space). And there is a Google spreadsheet in which I want to summarize some statistics on the folder with these files (moreover, there may be more subfolders inside the folder, documents which should also be taken into account).
I have placed all used tags in a column and I want the number of files marked with this tag to be counted in adjacent cells.
([[image: My spreadsheet]]

I think that this can be solved by writing functions for Google tables, but I didn’t manage to find something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it.
Be careful if you use folder's links, because `.getFiles()` interprets them as files too.

```
'use strict';

// идентификатор корневой папки
const rootId       = "qwe123"; // here from https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/qwe123
// имя страницы таблицы тегов
const sheetName    = "Tags"; // here spreadsheet's page name
// ячейки с наименованиями тегов
const tagsRange    = "C3:C";
// заголовок столбца вывода результатов подсчёта
const outputHeader = "D3";

function CountTags()
{
  const rootFolder  = DriveApp.getFolderById(rootId);
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);

  // составляем словарь тегов вида: { наименование: количество, ... }
  const labels      =
    Object.fromEntries(
      spreadsheet.getRange(tagsRange)
                 .getValues()
                 .flat()
                 .filter(x => x)
                 .map(x => [x, 0]));
                 

  const action =
    file =>
      file.getDescription() // извлекаем описание
         ?.split(" ") // разбиваем строку по-элементно
         ?.filter(x => x.startsWith("#")) // из полученных подстрок выделяем теги
         ?.map(x => x.substring(1)) // удаляем спец-символ
         ?.filter(x => x in labels) // отбираем ожидаемые теги
         ?.forEach(x => labels[x] = ++labels[x]); // производим подсчёт

  ProcessFilesRecursively(rootFolder, action);


  // устанавливаем результат в соответствующие ячейки
  SetColumn(spreadsheet, outputHeader, Object.values(labels))
}

/**
 * Проставляет значения в столбец, начиная с указанной ячейки.
 *
 * @param {Sheet} sheet Google spreadsheet.
 * @param {String} starts Строка, содержащая заголовочную ячейку заполняемого столбца.
 * @param {Array.<number>} values Устанавливаемые значения.
 */
function SetColumn(sheet, starts, values)
{
  const range  = sheet.getRange(starts);
  const column = range.getColumn();
  var row      = range.getRow();

  values.forEach(value =>
    sheet.getRange(row++,column).setValue(value));
}

/**
 * Перебирает файлы в папке и её подпапках, вызывая над каждой функцию action.
 *
 * @param {Folder} folder Рассматриваемая папка.
 * @param {Function} action Функция, выполняемая над каждым файлом в папке.
 */
function ProcessFilesRecursively(folder, action)
{
  /*
   * ВАЖНО!!! .getFiles() извлекает не только документы,
   * но и ссылки на папки, поэтому на них не должно быть тегов
   */
  const files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext())
  {
    action(files.next());
  }

  const subfolders = folder.getFolders();
  while (subfolders.hasNext())
  {
    ProcessFilesRecursively(subfolders.next(), action);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely accomplish this using Google Apps Script. Just to give you an idea, you need to use the Drive API and the Drive Labels API.

First you use the Drive Labels API to find the IDs of all the labels from the sheet. Once you get the IDs you use the Drive API to search all the files that have that particular label applied to them. After that you use the SpreadsheetApp class to change the values in the Sheet.

#### Sample code:

```js
function findLabeledDocs() {
  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); //Replace Sheet 1 with the name of your sheet
  var labelsRange = spreadsheet.getRange("B3:B9").getValues().flat(); //The ranges are fixed according to your sample image, however you can change them as required.
  var countRange = spreadsheet.getRange("C3:C9");
  var filesCount = [];
  var labelsIds = [];

  //Retrieves the list of all the labes within the domain
  var labels = Labels.Labels.list();

  for(var i=0; i<labels.labels.length; i++)
  {
    //From all the labels it finds the IDs of the ones that match the name of the range in the Sheet.
    if(labelsRange.includes(labels.labels[i].properties.title) == true)
    {
      labelsIds.push(labels.labels[i].id);
    }
  }

  //Finds all the files within the user's Drive that have the labels from the Sheet.

  for(var x=0; x<labelsIds.length; x++)
  {
    var param = {
      q: `'labels/${labelsIds[x]}' in labels`,
      fields: "items/title"
    };

    var files = Drive.Files.list(param);
    filesCount.push([files.items.length]);
  }

  //Changes the file count within the Sheet.
  countRange.setValues(filesCount);
}
```

All the code is missing is the fact that the default limit of files you can get in a single search is 100, you can set it to 1000 as that is the maximum, but that's the limit, so you would need to handle the part of working with different pages. But this is just for you to get an idea of how this works.

#### Note:

Make sure to enable the Drive API and the Drive Labels API in the advanced services of Google Apps Script that is located on the left side panel. I used `Labels` as the identifier of the Drive Labels API.

[image]

[image]

#### References:

- [How to enable Advanced services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services)
- [Page through lists of resources](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/pagination)
- [Method: files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Method: labels.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/labels/reference/rest/v2/labels/list)
- [Search for files with a specific label or field value](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files#label)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: Thanks a lot!
But it throws an error: `ReferenceError: Labels is not defined
findLabeledDocs @ Code.gs:10`

Comment: Sorry my bad. You need to add the Drive Labels API as well to the list of advanced services in Apps Script and call it “Labels”. Give me a couple minutes and I’ll update the answer adding that info.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! Now it starts, but gets me `GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drivelabels.labels.list failed with error: The user doesn't have permission to perform the requested operation.`

Comment: Although the folders and the table are available to me. And I also don’t see where the folder is specified from which folder to start searching for files for accounting.

Comment: @EgoPingvina about the error message, it is possible that you are not a [Drive Labels admin](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9292382), therefore you should not have access to manage Labels info.

Comment: @EgoPingvina For the folder part you can just get the folder ID from the URL when opening the Folder in a web browser and modify the query to add the folder part like `'labels/${labelsIds[x]}' in labels and 'FolderID' in parents`. But make sure you have Drive Labels admin rights to run the script, otherwise you will be getting the same permissions error.

Comment: I have editor rights but didn`t understand the part about URL. For example, My parent folder's URL is ".../drive/folders/qwe123", what's next?